# Row and column border not coming in excel file using php

Tags: php, xml, xlsx

I am using php and create excel file using table tag . please help me why other cell have not coming border. show screenshot for more detail .

[image]

code is as below :

I am using following code

// EXPORT ANALYSIS INTO XLS FILE
    function export($t_id,$type){

```
    // Send the headers
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=\"".getField('target_name','targets','t_id',$t_id).'_'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()).".xls\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header('Expires: -1');

    if($type == 'all'){
        $targets = $this->mdl_home->fetchAllTracedLocation($t_id,'N','ALL');
        echo '<table border="1" >
              <tr>
               <th>SR No.</th> 
               <th>Location</th> 
               <th>Zip code</th> 
               <th>Event Type</th>    
               <th>Date-Time</th>
              </tr>';

            $i = 1;                
            foreach($targets as $list) { 

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$list['location_address'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$list['location_zip_code'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$list['track_type'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime($list['created_date'])).'</td>';                      
                echo '</tr>';
                $i++;
            }            
            echo '</table>' ;
    }
```

}

Comment: You're not creating an excel file using table tag: you're creating an html markup file using tble tag but giving it an extension of .xls/.xlsx, so don't expect MS Excel to read it perfectly when it isn't really an Excel file that it's reading

Comment: How many Content Types?!? You can only have one `Content-Type` header, if you specify multiple different types as you have, all but the last one will be ignored

Comment: The MS Excel html reader isn't perfect: perhaps you should complain to Microsoft that their import doesn't handle borders correctly

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting proper output when you simply print the data first with out using header?

do try the following : hope it helps :

```
$name = "somename.xls";

header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$name");

header("Expires: 0");
```